# Haxe: access root package class if it's hidden behind class from another package

Tags: haxe

The code:

```
//./Main.hx
package;
import bar.Bar;
class Main {
    static var foo:Foo;
    static function main() {
        $type(foo); // I want it to be "Foo", but it's "bar.Foo"
    }
}

//./Foo.hx
package;
class Foo {}

//./bar/Bar.hx
package bar;
class Foo {}
class Bar {}
```

`Bar` is a library that I cannot change. It defines a class named `Foo` in file `Bar.hx`. I do not directly use `bar.Foo`, but use `bar.Bar`. I want to name my class `Foo`, it's a good name and I can't think of another, but I can't use it because it gets hidden behind `bar.Foo`. What can I do?

One of the solutions is to change `bar.Foo` declaration to

```
private class Foo {}
```

It works and does not break anything, but I do not want to change the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import bar.Bar` is a **module import**, which means it imports all types in the `Bar.hx` module. So if you want to prevent `bar.Bar.Foo` from being imported as well, you can explicitly import *only* the `Bar` type like this:

```
import bar.Bar.Bar;
```

This is explained in the [Import](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-import.html)-section of the Haxe manual.